# How to enhance mapping experience using table column?

Tags: interaction-design, tables

**Context**

I have been trying to design a page for an application that performs data migration tasks.

**Problem statement**

I have a page where all source DB tables and corresponding columns get matched with the target DB table and columns.

The issue I am facing is that it's possible to do mapping for 5 tables and each table having 30-40 rows. As of now, I have planned to show all table names in the sidebar example like list component and utilize the right side of space for table mapping.

Please check the link for a better understanding of the concept. Link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KHK58vD1ALe3zazyE0ff2ankE_68rNuc/view?usp=sharing

Is there any better way to do it? Thank you for help.

Edit: I tried to create a wireframe diagram. Please check: https://app.moqups.com/6yqahTxE5k/view/page/ad64222d5

Comment: Need some more screens to understand the context better? would be nice if the wireframes details how the current mapping has been planned

Comment: @Swapna updated please check.

Comment: Thanks for adding the information; it's better though to add images directly in the post itself, in case the links break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to edit the answer after our discussion, so please see one possible solution for the 'fixed' target tables.

This is just my suggestion, hope that more people could come with more ideas here. What I would have done is to create something similar like this below:

[image: Fixed 5 targets]

You would find the table names as names of tabs, so in one action you have the name and also the possibility to change pages. With the scroll down you can help the users with the high number of rows (columns) that the tables could have.

Also, the dropdown can be implemented as a Search&Select where users can search among all the columns in the database.

Good luck with your task,

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Design is good but I have a fixed number of target table which I need to accept, if I go for the above design they become optional.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So you have 5 different target tables, right? But the source could be from anywhere in your database source, is it?

Comment: Yes, Correct. I have implemented a solution that is able to handle it. I will share that here soon.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer. :)

Comment: I have implemented something like but table names on sides. But appreciate your efforts thank you.